# Calculate Record Row by Row and some calculation SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 15.0.2070.41, and I have a table like:

```
Name | Price | No_Of_Person | Name_Of_Person 
-----+-------+--------------+------------------
Nits |  100  |   2          | Risa, Bit            
Nits |  200  |   3          | Nits, Dish, Bit        
Nits |   80  |   4          | Bit, Risa, Nits, Dish 
Nits |   20  |   3          | Bit, Nits, Nash
```

There is a total of 5 members are there whose names are Nits, Dish, Risa, Bit, Nash
in this table name column shows the name of the person who had spend his own money.

How can I calculate which person will pay how much to Nits?

I tried something like:

```
Select 
    name, Item, Price, No_Of_Person, Name_Of_Persian, Note, Date,  
    Price / No_Of_Person as 'result' 
From 
    tb_Expense_Details 

SELECT 
    price, Name_Of_Person 
FROM
    tb_Expense_Details  
WHERE
    name = 'Risa' 
GROUP BY
    price, Name_Of_Person
```

Sample data:

```
ID  Name    Item    Price   No_Of_Persion   Name_Of_Persion Note    Date
1   nitis   ANY     50         2             Rishi,Nitish         2020-03-09
2   nishan  ANY     300        3             Rishi,Nitish,Nishant 2020-03-09
```

I am Getting output:

```
Name    Person  Price
nishant Nishant 100.000000000000
nishant Nitish  100.000000000000
nitish  Nitish  25.000000000000
nishant Rishi   100.000000000000
nitish  Rishi   25.000000000000
```

But I Want output Like:

```
Nishant  100
Nitish   125
Rishi    125
```

It Means Person column should not contain duplicate value it should be addition of respected price

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: its 15.0.2070.41

Comment: @Zhorov 200 will divided into 3 part but in last calculation Nits will get 66.66 * 2 = 133 from Dish and Bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach to get the expected result is the following statement. You need to split the values in the `Name_Of_Person` column and make aggregation:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Expence_Details ( 
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
   [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
   [Item] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
   [Price] [int] NULL, 
   [No_Of_Persion] [int] NULL, 
   [Name_Of_Persion] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
   [Note] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
   [Date] [date] NULL 
)
INSERT INTO tbl_Expence_Details
   (Name, Item, Price, No_Of_Persion, Name_Of_Persion)
VALUES   
   ('nitis',  'ANY', 50,  2, 'Rishi,Nitish'),
   ('nishan', 'ANY', 300, 3, 'Rishi,Nitish,Nishant')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   RTRIM(LTRIM(s.[value])) AS Person, 
   SUM(1.0 * t.Price / t.No_Of_Persion) AS Price
FROM tbl_Expence_Details t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Name_Of_Persion, ',') s
GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(s.[value]))
```

Result (without rounding and formatting):

```
Person  Price
Nishant 100.000000000000
Nitish  125.000000000000
Rishi   125.000000000000
```

Comment: its showing 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric' i thing  i need to convert data type?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Expence_Details](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Item] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Price] [int] NULL,
 [No_Of_Persion] [int] NULL,
 [Name_Of_Persion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Note] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Date] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: thanks a lot its working as i want.. thank u so much

Comment: if i am inserting two times same name its showing two records but it should be one record with total price why?

Comment: 1 nitish any      50 2          Rishi,Nitish                  2020-03-09
2 nishant any    300 3         Rishi,Nitish,Nishant  2020-03-09

Comment: output should for one name only one record should be display like addition of all record for respected person

Comment: But its showing multiples record for one name even-though we use group by also why its so... ??

Comment: i am asking another question as i want its going too long so but as of now i get my output